# In Selenium how exactly are the sendKeys() and setValue() methods different?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys, setattribute, setvalue

I've used both

```
WebElement.sendKeys('')
```

and

```
WebElement.setValue('')
```

In order to input text into fields.  The vast majority of the time they seem to act the same, but I've found a few cases where `setValue()` works but `sendKeys()` does not.

All I can find in the Selenium docs is that `sendKeys()` *'more accurately imitates user input'* then `setValue()`.  Does anyone know what is actually happening under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### sendKeys()

[`sendKeys()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) is the *Java* method from [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) to simulate typing into an element, which may set its value.

- Defination:

  ```
  void sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)
      Use this method to simulate typing into an element, which may set its value.

  Parameters:
      keysToSend - character sequence to send to the element

  Throws:
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - if keysToSend is null
  ```
- Usage:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("C.Peck@stackoverflow.com");
  ```

However there is no `setValue()` method in *Java* and the closest match seems to be `setAttribute()` *JavaScript* method.

---

### setAttribute()

[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) is the *JavaScript* method which sets the value of an attribute on the specified element. If the attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new attribute is added with the specified name and value.

- Syntax:

  ```
  Element.setAttribute(name, value);
  ```
- Example:

  - HTML:

    ```
    <button>Hello World</button>
    ```
  - JavaScript:

    ```
    var b = document.querySelector("button"); 
    b.setAttribute("name", "helloButton");
    b.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    ```
- Implementation through *Java* `executeScript()`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('attribute_name', 'new_value_for_element')");
  ```

Comment: The user is asking for `setValue()` not `setAttribute()`

Comment: `setValue()` is provided when interacting with `MobileElement` and functionally is very similar to `sendKeys`